# Sorting a character string in perl?

Tags: string, perl, sorting

Is there any in-built function in perl to sort characters in string like **sorted()** in python?

For example,

> $word = "honey";

i want output as "ehnoy".

Comment: That looks reversed, not sorted.

Comment: You mean you want to *reverse* it?

Comment: @izb:sorry. Sorting only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to split string into list of chars, sort it, and join list of chars using empty string,

```
my $sorted = join "", sort split //, $word;
```

assigned `ehnoy`

Comment: Thats i know that. I want to know about only **in-built functions** rather than making that as list of characters and then sort.

Comment: @user3440628 you can sort only lists; there is no built-in which could sort chars inside string.

Answer (score 2):

You could embed mpapec's solution in a subroutine that makes it LOOK like Perl has it built in...

```
sub sorted
{
   join "", sort split //, shift;
}

my $str = "honey";

print sorted $str;
```